# Unable to build the image using the OpenShift build service: Can't instantiate binary build, due to error reading/writing stream

Tags: syndesis

When I try to execute a build of the images of Syndesis using Minishift, it finishes with this error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
 io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:3.5.38:build (exec) on project s2i:
 Failed to execute the build: Unable to build the image using the
 OpenShift build service: Can't instantiate binary build, due to error
 reading/writing stream. Can be caused if the output stream was closed
 by the server. Connection reset
```

I cheched that minishift is running with "minishift status":

```
$ minishift status
Minishift:  Running
Profile:    minishift
OpenShift:  Running (openshift v3.11.0+82a43f6-231)
DiskUsage:  76% of 20G (Mounted On: /mnt/sda1)
CacheUsage: 1.679 GB (used by oc binary, ISO or cached images)
```

and checked that the proper project/pods are installed with "oc get pods" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that minishift was running out of space.

I could recover some space with the command

```
$ syndesis dev --cleanup
```

When you do this, make sure the [nip.io](https://nip.io/) domains work on your machine. If that's not the case, add the following entry to your /etc/hosts:

```
$IP    $IP.nip.io syndesis.$IP.nip.io docker-registry-default.$IP.nip.io
```

where $IP is the IP of minishift, which you can find with:

```
$ minishift ip
192.168.42.58
```